# How to remove css style on button click in javascript?

Tags: javascript, button

I have created an form in which I have made the input field disabled by default->

```
<input class="name"  type="text" maxlength="50" value="Hritika Agarwal" disabled="" />
```

I want to make this editable on button click. So created a button like this ->

```
 <button class="accept-btn" onclick="myFunction()">Edit</button>


   function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("name").removeAttribute("disabled");
   }
```

But It's not working.

I have even tried like this also->

```
     function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("name").style.disabled = "false";
    }
```

But again nothing happened.
How could I resolve this>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to select elemnt by class name use `getElementsByClassName`.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("name")[0].disabled = false;
```

If

select elemnt by id use `getElementById`.change input to

```
<input id="name"  type="text" maxlength="50" value="Hritika Agarwal" disabled="" />
```

then

```
 document.getElementById("name").disabled = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

You use `getElementById` to find an element with the id `name` but there is not such thing. Use `<input id="name"` instead of class, then the first will work.

The second can not work, since `disabled` is not a style-property.

Answer (score 2):

```
 function myFunction() {
   document.getElementsByClassName("name")[0].removeAttribute("disabled");
 }
```

Or

```
<input class="name" id="name"  type="text" maxlength="50" value="Hritika Agarwal" disabled="" />
```